# Serialization BigInteger: signum-magnitude mismatch

Tags: java, exception, serialization, rsa, biginteger

I'm encrypting data using Kaffe JVM (equivalent to java 1.1) and trying decrypting data with JDK7.

In my algorithm I use BigInteger (RSA encription). When I tested the application in JDK, all its OK, but when I trying to deserialize with JDK7 from a generated BigIntegers in Kaffe JVM I get this Exception listed below.

I was thinking in many causes of problem:

- Different JVMs: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV13214
- Problem with Big Endians and little endians
- problem with processor type (16-bits, 32 -bits 64-bits).

Any ideas how to fix or detect the cause of the problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: BigInteger: signum-magnitude mismatch
at java.math.BigInteger.readObject(BigInteger.java:3113)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1685)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1341)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
at commons.persistence.PersisterDataBigIntegerBuffer.fileToObjects(PersisterDataBigIntegerBuffer.java:87)
at commons.persistence.CryptoRSAFileManager.getDataFromFile(CryptoRSAFileManager.java:44)
at test.commons.csv.ParserTester.test(ParserTester.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a difference in serialization formats.

To solve this problem you are probably going to have to subclass BigInteger and override the readObject method once you figure out the storage format from the source JDK. To give you a hint on what you're in for, here is the relavant part of BigInteger's readObject from OpenJDK:

```
// Read the alternate persistent fields that we care about
int sign = fields.get("signum", -2);
byte[] magnitude = (byte[])fields.get("magnitude", null);

// Validate signum
if (sign < -1 || sign > 1) {
   String message = "BigInteger: Invalid signum value";
   if (fields.defaulted("signum"))
      message = "BigInteger: Signum not present in stream";
   throw new java.io.StreamCorruptedException(message);
}
```